# Random and unique from txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get random but unqiues lines/words from a txt file in Python but It doesnt work for me
this is my code :

```
f=open("Order#.txt", "r")
aaawdad = f.read()
words = aaawdad.split()
Repeat = len(words)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
df = pd.read_csv('Order#.txt', sep='\t')
uniques = df[df.columns[0]].unique()
for i in range(Repeat):
    Mainlink = 'https://footlocker.narvar.com/footlocker/tracking/startrack?order_number=' + uniques
    driver.get(Mainlink)
```

The text file looks like this :

```
Order#1
Order#2
Order#3
…
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't attach the file.

But I think you should put the lines of the text file to the list and then random the index.